# Prove that $\prod_{i=2}^n (1-1/i^2) = {n+1\over 2n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Prove $$\prod_{i=2}^n (1-1/i^2) = {n+1\over 2n}$$ for all n greater or equal to 2.

First of all, I'm well aware this exact question exists [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215259/prove-that-prod-i-2n-1-1-i2-n1-over-2n) Unfortunately, this post didn't help me, and is much too old for me to resurrect. For reference, I'm a undergraduate college student, in an introductory proof writing course.

Currently, I've made the following progress:

We wish to show that $\prod_{i=2}^n (1-1/i^2) = {n+1\over 2n}$ for every integer n greater than or equal to 2. We will proceed via induction.

For the base step, let n be equal to 2. Then, $1 – (1/2^2) = ¾$, and $(2+1)/2(2) = ¾$. Therefore, $\prod_{i=2}^n (1-1/i^2) = {n+1\over 2n}$ at n = 2.

Next, assume that $\prod_{i=2}^k (1-1/i^2) = {k+1\over 2k}$ up until some integer k. We wish to show that this is true at k+1 as well.

$\prod_{i=2}^k (1-1/i^2) = {k+1\over 2k}$ can be written as ${(k+1)-1\over k} * {(k+1)+1\over k}$, or ${k\over k} * {k+2\over k}$.

k/k is 1, of course. but I'm not sure where to go from k+2/k. Or maybe I made some other mistake? I can't decipher user17762's comment under his answer to the linked question, nor the OP's edit after the "so". Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you! I think I fixed it to the proper extent, how did I do?

Comment: The upper bound of the product must be $k$ and not $n$. You have to change the index $k$ of the product to $i$ for example.

Comment: Avoid the use of characters as ¾, use MathJax to write $\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Also, avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics, where is has other meanings. Use (ideally) juxtaposition, `\times` ($\times$) or `\cdot` ($\cdot$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an algebra mistake: $\frac{k+1}{2k}$ cannot be written as $\frac kk \frac{k+2}k$.

You've established the base step for $n=2$. To finish the proof by induction, first you **assume** the claim holds for $n=k$, so substitute $k$ in place of $n$ in the assertion:
$$\prod_{i=2}^{k}\left(1-\frac1{i^2}\right) = \frac{k+1}{2k}\tag1$$
You must now **show** that the claim holds for $n=k+1$:
$$\prod_{i=2}^{k+1}\left(1-\frac1{i^2}\right) = \frac{(k+1)+1}{2(k+1)}\tag2$$
The key is to observe that the LHS of (1) lives inside of the LHS of (2):
$$\prod_{i=2}^{k+1}\left(1-\frac1{i^2}\right)=\left[\prod_{i=2}^{k}\left(1-\frac1{i^2}\right)\right] \cdot \left(1-\frac1{(k+1)^2}\right)\tag3$$
In (3), the quantity in square brackets equals $\frac{k+1}{2k}$, by assumption (1). Given this, can you obtain the RHS of (2)?

Comment: I didn't mean to say that ${k+1\over 2k}$ was equal to ${k\over k} * {k+2\over k}$, but rather that the left hand side was equal to ${k\over k} * {k+2\over k}$. It was my understanding of inductive proofs that you aren't allowed to say your second step here. You have to take one of the sides, replace k with k+1, and then turn it into the other side. If you replace k with k+1 on both sides, then you've assumed what you're trying to prove. Such was what I thought, in any case.

Comment: Agreed, a proper proof will assume the $n=k$ case (equation 1) and then prove the $n=k+1$ case (equation 2). To do so, you start with the LHS of (2), then write (3), then substitute (1), and finally arrive at the RHS of (2). However, I don't see how replacing $k$ with $k+1$ in $\frac{k+1}{2k}$ yields $\frac{k+2}k$; it gets you $\frac{k+2}{2k+2}$ (which is the RHS of (2)).

Comment: Ah, I apologize, I was reading your response wrong. I saw this as a series of sequential steps rather than (1) being the inductive assumption, (2) being what we want to show, and (3) being the first step into proving (2). I've been able to prove the desired goal with this answer as a basis and a little help from the linked post, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For induction you need to multiply $\frac{n+1}{2n}$ by $1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}$. What do you mean by $k$?

Without induction: By using $1-1/i^2=\frac{(i-1)}{i}\times\frac{(i+1)}{i}$,

$$\prod_{i=2}^n(1-1/i^2)=\frac{1}{2}\times\underline{\left[\frac{3}{2}\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{4}{3}\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{5}{4}...\frac{(n-3)}{(n-2)}\times\frac{(n-1)}{(n-2)}\frac{(n-2)}{(n-1)}\times\frac{(n)}{(n-1)}\frac{(n-1)}{n}\right]}\times\frac{(n+1)}{n}$$
Hence, we have
$$\prod_{i=2}^n(1-1/i^2)=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

for reference, I'm an economist so don't mind if my notation is not a precise one. However, I'm usually trying to keep up with the mathematicians. Let us begin with your proof. We'll do the proof by induction.

1. The case where $k=2$, we have that $1-\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1+2}{2(2)}$
2. Let $n\rightarrow k$, with this we make the following inductive assumption:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)=\frac{k+1}{2k}
\end{equation}
3. Let us now check whether $P(k)\Longrightarrow P(k+1)$, which we'll do in the following way:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)=\underbrace{\frac{k+1}{2k}}_{\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)}\left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)=\\
\frac{k+1}{2k}\left(\frac{(k+1)^2-1}{(k+1)^2}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{2k}\left(\frac{(k+1)^2-1}{(k+1)}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{2k}\left(\frac{(k+1-1)(k+1+1)}{(k+1)}\right)=\\
\underbrace{\frac{k+2}{2(k+1)}}_{P(k+1)}\\
\therefore P(k)\Longrightarrow P(k+1)
\end{equation}